# Memory utilization in Python and working of Garbage Collector

Tags: python, memory-management, garbage-collection, dynamic-memory-allocation

As we know integer (int) is immutable in Python. We cannot change the value of an int object in-place(without changing its reference).

I want to understand the working of garbage collector in the following scenario.

```
from ctypes import c_long
a = 1000
while a < 1010:
    print(id(a), c_long.from_address(id(a)))
    a = a + 1
```

When I run the above code, I get the following output :

```
140548768404176 c_long(1)
140548768406160 c_long(1)
140548768404176 c_long(1)
140548768406160 c_long(1)
140548768404176 c_long(1)
140548768406160 c_long(1)
140548768404176 c_long(1)
140548768406160 c_long(1)
140548768404176 c_long(1)
140548768406160 c_long(1)
```

**Note**: c_long.from_address(id()) is used to get the reference count of a value or variable.

*I am aware of the fact that when we assign a variable with some value, and when the reference count becomes 0, it removes the reference to that value. And now that freed space can be utilized again.*

I want to understand how the memory block gets reassigned immediately and only these 2 blocks are used.

Comment: I may be naive but I don't see a problem. When `a` is `1003`, `1003` object has count 1. When you execute `1003 + 1`, `1004` is created in the next available location. When you assign `1004` to `a`, the count of `1003` becomes 0, freeing its location. Unless something else fills it up and doesn't get released in time, this location will be available for the result of `1004 + 1`. In this way, the two locations alternate, as each is freed only after the other is allocated.